# How do I get Carrierwave to delete a file from S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I have a vanilla Carrierwave, Fog, S3 setup. Uploading to S3 is fine, but when I destroy the record in my rails console locally, or I delete from within my web app via a `Delete` link, it doesn't remove the file on S3.

In fact, this is what my log looks like:

```
Started DELETE "/posts/13" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-30 04:19:39 -0500
Processing by PostsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"jcyevWU9M=", "id"=>"13"}
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE (("posts"."ancestry" ILIKE '13/%' OR "posts"."ancestry" = '13'))
  Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles"  WHERE "roles"."resource_id" = $1 AND "roles"."resource_type" = $2  [["resource_id", 13], ["resource_type", "Post"]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1  [["id", 13]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts
Completed 302 Found in 401ms (ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```

This is my `file_uploader.rb` file:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "files/#{SecureRandom.uuid()}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(pdf)
  end
end
```

This is my `Post.rb` model file:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: posts
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  status     :string(255)
#  title      :string(255)
#  photo      :string(255)
#  body       :text
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#  user_id    :integer
#  ancestry   :string(255)
#  file       :string(255)
#

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  belongs_to :user
  resourcify

  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

This is my delete action on my `PostsController.rb`:

```
  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

I have never been able to get a file to be deleted from this S3 bucket with this AWS IAM user I created for this app.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your uploader. You are using secure random for store dir.

```
def store_dir
   "files/#{SecureRandom.uuid()}"
end
```

When carrierwave try to delete file, Then due to random value store_dir point to some other place. I am sure you also not able to display this file anywhere.

So try something like this or something that is not randomly changes.

```
def store_dir
  "files/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

Comment: You are 100% on the money re not being able to display this file anywhere. Interesting! So is there no way for me to get random folder names?

Comment: No this is not possible. You always have some path that can be track by id or name or any other model's attribute.

Comment: So is it just the file names that can be random? - https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files

Comment: Yes this url is just to generate random file name.

Comment: @marcamillion You can generate random folder names but you have to store it at you model then. (and include it in `store_dir`-method like `"files/#{model.my_secure_folder_name ||= SecureRandom.uuid()}/"`

Comment: just chipping in on the `So is there no way for me to get random folder names?` part of this. If you want assets to be hard to guess, you could use UUIDs as a replacement for the integers used in the ID of your models. That way you make both the model and the file less predictable while maintaining the ability to debug the relation between file- and record-storage.
Gotcha Make sure that the relations use strings (article.id is uuid, comment.article_id is string) and custom behavior in your controller is cool with it.
https://pawelurbanek.com/uuid-order-rails is a good article on the subject.